# How do I find the probability of occurrence of 2 events in this question?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> What is the probability of occurrence of at least two of the three
>   events if $P(A) = 0.38, P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0.1, P(A \cap B' \cap C')
>  = 0.17$ and $ P(A'\cap B \cap C) = 0.12 $

I'm guessing this question is based on some sort of formula from sets I'm not aware of. Can anyone help?

Comment: "some sort of formula from sets I'm not aware of" Don't think so much in terms of formulas. Draw a diagram, write a table, anything that helps _you_ understand your problem better. Formulas are just calculations you do many times. If a formula to apply doesn't instantly pop into your head, and you really want one, then use the understanding that the diagrams or tables gave you and _make one_. You don't have to be an Authority On Mathematics to do so; anyone can make formulas, whenever they feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute it using Venn's diagram of algebraically:

for "at least two events" use this:
$P(A∩B∩C)+P(A′∩B∩C)+(P(A∩B∩C′)+P(A∩B'∩C))=0.1+0.12+0.11=0.33$

for "exactly two events" use this:
$P(A′∩B∩C)+(P(A∩B∩C′)+P(A∩B'∩C))=0.12+0.11=0.23$

In both cases you use this:
$P(A∩B∩C′)+P(A∩B'∩C)=P(A)-P(A∩B∩C)-P(A∩B′∩C′)=0.38-0.1-0.17=0.11$

as
$P(A)=P(A∩B∩C′)+P(A∩B'∩C)+P(A∩B∩C)+P(A∩B′∩C′)$

For a graphical explanation check this diagram:https://gs-post-images.grdp.co/2017/6/set-6_venn-img1496828993844-80-rs-high-webp.JPG

Comment: Can you explain me the steps? I'm not able to follow. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: How did you get $0.11$ from $(P(A \cap B \cap C') + P(A \cap B' \cap C))?

Comment: explanation added

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of answer: There are three ways that exactly two of the events can happen, and there are many ways to describe those three ways. Here is one description which makes direct use of the given numbers:

- Either $A$ happens or it doesn't

  - If $A$ happens, then it cannot be the case that both $B$ and $C$ happens, and it cannot be the case that neither $B$ nor $C$ happens, but anything else is valid
  - If $A$ doesn't happen, then both $B$ and $C$ must happen

Comment: If you really want formulas, then here are two that you might have seen and which are directly applied in the proof that I sketched above (or at least the one I thought of when I wrote it): For any event $X$ (you might have to try a few different until you find a suitable one) we have $P(X) = P(X\cap A) + P(X\cap A')$, and for any $Y$ (again, you may have to try a bit to find a suitable one) we have $P(Y') = 1-P(Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

$A=(A\cap B^{\complement}\cap C^{\complement})\cup(A\cap B\cap C)\cup(A\cap B\cap C^{\complement})\cup(A\cap B^{\complement}\cap C)$

The $4$ sets on RHS are disjoint so that:$$0.38=P(A)=0.17+P(A\cap B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C^{\complement})+P(A\cap B^{\complement}\cap C)$$

and consequently: $$P(A\cap B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C^{\complement})+P(A\cap B^{\complement}\cap C)+P(A^{\complement}\cap B\cap C)$$$$=0.38-0.17+0.12=0.33$$